# SQL, checking value against another value and returning both

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, something like below:

```
my_ID  fName  lName friend_ID
001    John   Smith 002
002    Mark   Math  003
```

I want a query that will get the fName, lName for my_ID, but also check the value for friend_ID against my_ID values, and when it finds a match return the fName, lName in a different row.

New table should be something like:

```
My Name      Friend Name
John Smith   Mark Math
```

Answer (score 0):

**Self join** is what you are looking for.

Considering there will be all ways 1 friend only.

```
SELECT CONCAT(T1.fName,' ',T1.lName) AS My_Name,
       CONCAT(T2.fName,' ',T2.lName) AS Friend_Name
        FROM table_name T1
        INNER JOIN table_name T2 ON T1.my_ID = T2.friend_ID
```

If the no .of friends can be 0(No friend),1(Single friend),1+(More friends)

```
SELECT CONCAT(T1.fName,' ',T1.lName) AS My_Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(T2.fName,' ',T2.lName)) AS FriendsNames
        FROM table_name T1
        LEFT JOIN table_name T2 ON T1.my_ID = T2.friend_ID
        GROUP BY T1.my_ID
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(A.fName, ' ', A.lName) as My_Name, 
CONCAT(B.fName, ' ', B.lName) as Friend_Name
FROM table_name A
INNER JOIN table_name B ON A.my_ID = B.friend_ID
```